# How do I debug multi-touch for a Unity on Android platform?

Tags: unity, android, debugging

I'm trying to implement multi-touch in my game but there are many bugs so far and I need a way to get info on all of the touches as the game is running. So far I haven't found any way to do this.

Comment: Does it have to be a build? Do you just need to debug multi-touch? If so, you can simulate multiple touches desktop (editor) side.

Comment: The Input API seems to have some straightforward methods for enumerating touches. Please edit your question to demonstrate the errors you're facing, and how you've tried using the Input API to troubleshoot them so far. Once we know what you've tried, we can help you find methods you haven't tried yet.